# outgoing sms activity link to provider when using multiple providers?

Tags: api, database, sms, civisms

I'm testing out multiple sms providers, and I'm using the api to do reads for reporting on the back end, but I can't seem to figure out how the system knows which sms provider sent a particular sms. The Activity table doesn't seem to have  provider_id reference of any kind unless I'm missing it. Is it in an attached table or something? I can't find a list of providers either. Is that in the database?

Comment: Which if any sms based extensions are you using?

Comment: Just Twilio at the moment, but looking to use a new one in addition

Answer (score 1):

From the db schema https://doc.symbiotic.coop/dev/civicrm/latest/schema/tables/civicrm_sms_provider.html

It looks like you might be after the sms_provider_id from the civicrm_mailing table, or sms_provider_id from the civicrm_action_schedule table.

Comment: I found the one in action_schedule, but that table is empty, so I think that's only scheduled items, and I've never scheduled anything ahead of time, so that makes sense. The mailing table doesn't look complete either. There are recent outgoing sms messages that don't appear, and in fact the table only has 19 entries total, and only 5 with the subject populated. Any clue where the rest of the data might be?